# Найти количество N-значных чисел, у которых сумма цифр равна их произведению (оптимизировать код)

Tags: python

Нужно: Найти количество N-значных чисел, у которых сумма цифр равна их произведению (оптимизировать код)

Моя неудачная попытка (Код медленный):

```
def cond(a):
    sum = 0
    mult = 1
    while a > 0:
        mult *= a % 10
        sum += a % 10
        a = int(a / 10)

    return sum == mult


def foo(n):
    n = int(n)
    if n == 1:
        return "10 0"

    req_num = 10**n
    prev_num = 10**(n-1)

    min_num = None
    counter = 0

    for i in range(prev_num, req_num):
        if cond(i):
            print(i)
            counter += 1
            if min_num is None:
                min_num = i

    return str(counter) + " " + str(min_num)


print(foo(3))
```

**Для 8-значных и выше чисел не справляется.**
Как можно улучшить алгоритм? Я нагуглил решение этой проблемы на C++, но не могу перевести код на Python и вообще понять алгоритм, который там используется: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1972973.html
Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то детально опишет используемый там алгоритм. Понял только то, что там как-то используются сочетания к отсортированным числам, благодаря чему количество вычислений уменьшается.

Answer (score 2):

Упростил:

0. Если n=1, то все 10 чисел являются искомыми, минимальное - 0.
1. Перебираем все наборы чисел от 1 до 9 включительно.
2. Если количество цифр n, а их сумма и произведение равны n, то увеличиваем ответ на число [перестановок с повторениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) для данного набора.
3. Делаем отсечение по достижению или превышению произведения и по слишком маленькой сумме.
4. Первый найденный набор образует минимальное число.

---

Изначальный алгоритм:

1. Перебираем все различные наборы чисел от 2 до 9 (включительно), произведение которых равно n, а сумма - количеству чисел в наборе (обозначим k).
2. Для каждого такого набора чисел считаем [число сочетаний](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) из n по k и умножаем на количество различных [перестановок с повторениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) для данного набора.
3. Суммируем все числа из прошлого пункта.

Ещё есть особый случай - для однозначных чисел решением является ещё и 0.

Comment: Спасибо за обратную связь. А что означает "упорядоченный набор из k"?

Comment: А почему "сумма n-k" она разве не должна быть == n??

Comment: @CoffeeinTime, немного накосячил. Сумма должна быть просто k (я сначала написал n-k), потому что оставшиеся n-k мы заполняем единицами, которые являются частью суммы, но не повлияют на произведение. Под упорядоченными я имел в виду, что различные (т. е. по сути не упорядоченные) - в общем, при переборе это будет означать, что каждое последующее число будет не меньше предыдущего (потому так и назвал). Поправил ответ.

Comment: @CoffeeinTime, переписал алгоритм.

Comment: Для 4х значных чисел у меня под условие (сумма и произведение цифр числа равны) попало число 1124. Я попытался подсчитать для него число перестановок с повторениями, но оно выдает 24, а должно быть 12.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Xv77x1Y
вот по этой формуле пытался

Comment: @CoffeeinTime, формулу в википедии прочитай внимательно. У тебя знаменатель неправильный. Должно быть 2! * 1! * 1!.

Answer (score 0):

Вышел такой код. Следуя ответу @Quertiy, можно сделать лучше, но не знаю как.

```
def check(number):
    s, m = 0, 1
    for digit in str(number) :
        digit = int(digit)
        s += digit
        m *= digit
    return s == m

# input n
while True :
    n = input("Введите N: ")
    if n.isdigit() :
        n = int(n)
        break
    else :
        print("Допустимы только натуральные числа!")

numbers = range(int("1" * n), int("1" + "0" * n))
numbers = filter(lambda x: "0" not in str(x), numbers)
numbers = tuple(filter(lambda x: check(x), numbers))

print(len(numbers))
```

Пример:

```
Введите N: 8
224
```

Comment: Эм.. Этот код работает быстрее кода из вопроса?

Comment: Не знаю, не проверял. Но справляется с 8-значными и более числами.